# Strange behavior of animation in Easeljs

Tags: javascript, html, animation, easeljs, onmouseclick

i'm only began to learn Javascript, so i have some troubles with animation in EaselJs. I'm trying to move object on mouse click (that's ok as i've expected), but when i'm try to add animation of movement in proper way, my animation doesn't acts, just stops at one frame when object moves. Here's the code of main.js and example of problem: http://rustem.ucoz.com/onMouseRun/index.html

```
var canvas;
var stage;
var imgCharRun = new Image();
var imgCharIdle = new Image();
var bmpAnimation;
var canvasx;
var isClicked = false;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    canvasx = canvas.offsetLeft;
    imgCharRun.src = "monsterRun.png";
    imgCharIdle.src = "monsterIdle.png";
    startGame();
}

function startGame(){
    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.enableMouseOver(10);

    var spriteSheet = new createjs.SpriteSheet({
    images: [imgCharRun, imgCharIdle], 
    frames: {width: 64, height: 64, regX: 32, regY: 32}, 
    animations: {   
    walk: [0, 9, "walk"],
    idle: [10, 20, "idle"]
    }
    });
    bmpAnimation = new createjs.BitmapAnimation(spriteSheet);
    bmpAnimation.gotoAndPlay ("idle");
    bmpAnimation.scaleX = 1;
    bmpAnimation.x = canvas.width/2;
    bmpAnimation.y = canvas.height-100;
    bmpAnimation.currentFrame = 9;
    stage.addChild(bmpAnimation);
    createjs.Ticker.addListener(window);
    createjs.Ticker.useRAF = true;
    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(30);
}
document.onmousedown = function(e) {
    isClicked = true;
    window.mousex = e.clientX-canvasx;
}

function isMouseClicked() {
    if (isClicked){
        moveToMouse();
    }
}

function moveToMouse() {
    if(bmpAnimation.x<mousex) {
        bmpAnimation.x+=5;
        bmpAnimation.gotoAndPlay("walk");
        bmpAnimation.scaleX = -1;
    }
    if(bmpAnimation.x>mousex) {
        bmpAnimation.x-=5;
        bmpAnimation.gotoAndPlay("walk");
        bmpAnimation.scaleX = 1;
    }

}
function tick() {
    stage.update();
    isMouseClicked();
}
```

Please, help me with this problem:

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `gotoAndPlay("walk")` every frame while the mouse is down, so it constantly sets the animation to the first frame of the walk animation. You need a flag to indicate if the animation is running already, and ensure you only call it one time.

Comment: Thanks, i'll try to make it. But if i'll face with a problem, can i hope on your help?

Comment: Ok, i've changed something to fix this bug, but another problem has appeared. Now animation stops only sometimes, and i know reasons of it. http://rockfor.us/onMouseRun/index.html

Comment: Earlier i've tried to make primitive movement by simply adding or subtracting 

5pixels from .x coordinate of character. But if i wanted character to stop when 

character.x==mouse.x, the problem appeared, because character.x was just roughly 

close to the mouse.x, but not ==mousex. How can i make not primitive movement to 

mouseclick?

Comment: @Rustem - Use distance measurement instead of a precise check: `Math.abs(currentX-destinationX) > threshold`.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved, thanks. Here is what i wanted: http://rockfor.us/onMouseRun/index.html